# Magento 2 with blank theme : no product on the homepage

Tags: theme-fallback, parent-child-theme, magento-2.1.3

With Blank Theme activated on my fresh install of Magento 2.1.3, all the sample data products of the front page don't show up anymore.

Is this a bug ? If not, how can I get the products to show up in my custom theme which inherits from the blank theme ?

Comment: Have you find product on category page or not?

Comment: No, nothing shows up if I click on categories of the menu in the homepage.

Comment: After reinstalling Magento 2.1.3, I realized that sampledata show up properly with Luma theme, but they don't show up with blank theme because no product has the "weight" attribute set. As soon as a weight is set, it's fine with blank theme. So, I'm now wondering where such difference between the two themes come from.